# Make Zara like product page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make product page like in Zara's App. I am having trouble implementing their app functionality like in the app. They have an area where you can view images, that can be implemented using `PageView` widget but How do I implement the bottom sheet functionality which comes up when swiped up ? I tried using `DraggableScrollableSheet` but then I cannot use `PageView` for images because `DraggableScrollableSheet` is there which takes up the whole screen. My current implementaion is as follows :

```
class _IndividualProductState extends State<IndividualProduct> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
         child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            //  ---------------Image container -----------------------------------------

            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.78,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: PageView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                controller: PageController(initialPage: 1),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(
                    "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81pV8zF-RML._AC_UL320_ML3_.jpg",
                     fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                  Image.network(
                    "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81pV8zF-RML._AC_UL320_ML3_.jpg",
                     fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // -------------------------- For Product Description ---------------------------------------
            Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              body: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                minChildSize: 0.17,
                initialChildSize: 0.17,
                maxChildSize: 0.93,
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                    child: ListView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      controller: scrollController,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(
                          heightFactor: 0.3,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Icon(MaterialCommunityIcons.minus, size: 32),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 0),
                          child: CustomText(
                            "COMFORT KNIT TEXTURED TROUSER",
                            weight: FontWeight.w500,
                            size: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),

            //  Close icon to close the product page
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  size: 32,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
          // ),
        ),
        // ),
      ),
    );
    // );
  }
}
```

I want the images to be scrollable also can bring up the description sheet via swipe up.

Comment: Could you please post sample code that all defined in one single main.dart  to reproduce your problem? That would be great for any one to help you easily. Also add expected and actual output. If possible, add screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a component that is called Backdrop in the Material Design system. According to [Material Design's Backdrop page:](https://material.io/components/backdrop/)

> A backdrop appears behind all other surfaces in an app, displaying contextual and actionable content.

I think the Backdrop widget is still missing from the out-of-the-box Flutter libraries because the Backdrop component design is still considered in beta phase by the Material Design system.

However, there is [a reusable implementation by Hans Muller from the Flutter samples gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/backdrop.dart), and [a detailed Medium article about the Backdrop by Matt Sullivan](https://medium.com/flutter/decomposing-widgets-backdrop-b5c664fb9cf4) that will help you build your own version of the Backdrop component that suits your needs.

If this is not what you need, please comment with a clip or images showing the behaviour you'd like exactly. A runnable `main` dart snippet of what you have right now would be extra helpful for me to understand what you are trying to achieve.